# ImageList promises me Alphablending, but how do I enable it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, alphablending

I want my buttons to have images with alphablending on them.
As instructed I've included a `TXPManifest` component on my mainform.
Below are some images I've loaded into my project.

[image: Imagelist editor]

However my `BitBtn`, which is linked to the imagelist via an ActionList still looks off.

[image: BitBtn is off]  <<-- It looks like this at runtime, Yikes!

How do I get Delphi 2007 running on my Windows 7 laptop to actually use the **alpha channel** the ImageList keeps teasing me with?

In response to @RRUZ, here are the imagelist properties:
[image]
*(Note the absence of a `colordepth` property)*

**EDIT**
The alpha-blending **does** work with the TMS `AdvGlowButton`: [image: AdvGlowButton with alphablending correct]
So it's probably not a ImageList issue, as much as it is an BitBtn issue.

**UPDATE 2**
Downloaded and installed `PngComponents`. Putting a `TPNGImageList` on a blank form instantly crashes D2007. *(Maybe something in the settings/path/etc, but I'm drifting too far from the original issue so I'm dropping the png pursuit).*
So that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you setting the property  `ColorDepth` of the TimageList to `cd32Bit`?

Comment: @RRUZ, I don't think Delphi-2007 `ImageList` has a ColorDepth property, see the updated question.

Comment: If it doesn't have the ColorDepth property then you can set `ImageList1.Handle := ImageList_Create(...)`. Then populate the list at runtime by loading icons from resources. That's what I had to do in D6.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it seems to work correct with the TMS controls like AdvGlowButton, so it's likely a BitBtn issue.

Comment: Does that Delphi have the TButton that supports images?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, just tested, nope no support for images on TButton.

Comment: The purple background hints the bitmap to be 24bpp. Anyway with an 32bpp bitmap I see black artifact instead of purple. I'm using TPngImageList for D2007 for this kind of stuff, but it may not be possible to find the base library 'pngimage' since it has now long been incorporated into the VCL.

Comment: What does TXPManifest got anything to do with it? D2007 already attaches a manifest.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, The imagelist editor specifically told me _(see screenshot)_ to include a XPManifest, so I did.

Comment: @Johan, I guess CN Wizards was lazy to explain version requirement, just checked the manifests, the only differences are assemblyIdentity name, one is "DelphiApplication", the other is "CodeGear RAD Studio", and assemblyIdentity version, one is "1.0.0.0", the other is the actual version of BDS.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: `TXPManifest` is a legacy component for old Delphi versions before the `TThemeManager` component logic was rolled into the VCL natively.  It does not matter how your app gets a manifest, only that it get compiled with one enabled, and the manifest has to enable ComCtrls v6 (which the default manifest does).

Comment: `TXPManifest` was for Delphi versions that didn't inherently support theming. In D2007, you can use `Project->Options->Application->Enable Themes` (not sure of exact wording; don't have 2007 installed here). There may be a conflict between the manifests that isn't apparent without actually viewing resources. The best solution is *not* to use `TXPManifest`, and enable theme support for the project instead. `CN Wizards` is wrong; it should have mentioned that the note applied to Delphi 7 and earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to refer to Anders Melander's [Blog](http://melander.dk/).

Hes has published 2 relevant posts both related to *alpha blending* under *Delphi 2007*:

- [Alpha Blended Splash Screen in Delphi - Part 1](http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash/)
- [Alpha Blended Splash Screen in Delphi - Part 2](http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash2)

Very instructives.